# Limit of finite measure on a $\sigma$-field

Tags: real-analysis

let $\mu$ be a finite measure on the $\sigma$-field $F$. If $A_{n} \in F, n=1,2,...$ and $A=\lim_{n} A_{n}$, show that $\mu (A)=\lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(A_{n})$

Comment: This will follow from writing down the definition of a limit of a sequence of sets.